# How to write argument for Chrome/Chromium's '--enable-features=' flag

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, google-chrome-os, chromium-os

I am trying to modify Chromium browser's behavior in Chromium OS.

When I execute Chromium browser, I can handover arguments with '--enable-features=' flag.

And I found a argument (#enable-virtual-keyboard) from Available list in `chrome://flags`.

Then I executed Chromium browser like below.

```
example instruction # /opt/google/chrome/chrome --incognito --enable-features=enable-virtual-keyboard
```

And when I check the flags in `chrome://version`, I could see the arguments.

```
Command Line: /opt/google/chrome/chrome --blahblah --enable-features=enable-virtual-keyboard
```

But actually the virtual keyboard is not working.

When I enable the argument (virtual keyboard) from `chrome://flags` manually. It works well and I could see the Virtual Keyboard.

What is wrong? I would appreciate it if you guys advise me.

Answer (score 1):

`--enable-features` actually takes the name of a *feature*, not the name of a *flag*. [The Chromium documentation](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/HEAD/docs/configuration.md) explains the difference, but to simplify somewhat, a flag is sort of a user-visible interface to a feature or a command-line switch.

Anyway, to do what you want, you need to find out what feature or command-line switch the `enable-virtual-keyboard` flag toggles. Searching for `enable-virtual-keyboard` in [Chromium Code Search](https://source.chromium.org/chromium) brings us to [these lines in about_flags.cc](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:chrome/browser/about_flags.cc;l=3340-3342;drc=c1664832449cb5c4caaddbc6b79d50a3006fd30b):

```cpp
    {"enable-virtual-keyboard", flag_descriptions::kVirtualKeyboardName,
     flag_descriptions::kVirtualKeyboardDescription, kOsCrOS,
     SINGLE_VALUE_TYPE(keyboard::switches::kEnableVirtualKeyboard)},
```

That last line tells us what we're looking for: that this flag is actually backed by a command-line switch, not a feature. Clicking on `kEnableVirtualKeyboard` shows us [its definition](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:ash/public/cpp/keyboard/keyboard_switches.cc;l=10;drc=de68be3f18ba99cc01d75903e167ca09bade253c):

```cpp
const char kEnableVirtualKeyboard[] = "enable-virtual-keyboard";
```

So, adding `--enable-virtual-keyboard` to your command line should have the same effect as flipping the flag. (I should note, though, that there are a number of things that can break the virtual keyboard, so you may have to do other things to get it working.)

For the sake of completeness, if you'd found that it was actually backed by a feature, like [the `gesture-properties-dbus-service` flag](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:chrome/browser/about_flags.cc;l=5894-5897;drc=c1664832449cb5c4caaddbc6b79d50a3006fd30b), for example:

```cpp
    {"gesture-properties-dbus-service",
     flag_descriptions::kEnableGesturePropertiesDBusServiceName,
     flag_descriptions::kEnableGesturePropertiesDBusServiceDescription, kOsCrOS,
     FEATURE_VALUE_TYPE(chromeos::features::kGesturePropertiesDBusService)},
```

Then clicking `kGesturePropertiesDBusService` takes us to [its definition](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:ash/constants/ash_features.cc;l=619;drc=de68be3f18ba99cc01d75903e167ca09bade253c) which specifies the feature name:

```cpp
const base::Feature kGesturePropertiesDBusService{
    "GesturePropertiesDBusService", base::FEATURE_DISABLED_BY_DEFAULT};
```

...so in that case you'd pass `--enable-features=GesturePropertiesDBusService` to enable the flag from your command line.